# Is $U(n)$ isomorph to $SO(2n)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I know that $U(1)$ is isomorph to $SO(2)$ and that $U(n)$ is a subgroup of $SO(2n)$. Is $U(n)$ not just a subgroup but even isomorph to $SO(2n)$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $U(n)$ has smaller dimension $n^2 < 2n (2n-1) / 2$ for $n>1$.

With the identification $C^n\simeq R^{2n}$, unitary matrices are much more "special", as they not only preserve norms, but are also complex-linear transformation. This is not automatic for real-linear transformation of $R^{2n}$.